# Need of a redis server in a centralized setup

Tags: database, redis, elasticsearch, logstash

I have gone through the documentation on the Logstash server to find out that we require a redis server which will act as a broker.
Here is the link:

```
http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.12/tutorials/getting-started-centralized
```

But what is not clear to me is why we use Redis at all as a broker?

We could rather simply directly ship the logs to the elastic search from logstash itself, that would save us the need of the redis broker. Then why do we go for a shipper and a indexer ?

Need clear explanation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find an answer here:

`https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/VakCOAzZI8k`

Redis basically acts as a temporary key value store for raw shipper information which is then parsed by the indexer. Then the log info is ultimately stored in elasticsearch, and not in redis.

Apparently the idea is to offload indexing to a server dedicated to such tasks, as indexing is CPU intensive. Redis being called a broker seems appropriate, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

When using Logstash with Redis, you can configure Redis to only store all the log entries in memory which would like a in memory queue (like memcache).

You mat come to the point where the number of logs sent will not be processed by Logstash and it can bring down your system on constant basis (observed in our environment).

If you feel Redis is an overhead for your disk, you can configure it to store all the logs in memory until they are processed by logstash.